# Jquery UI working in Visual Studio 2012 asp.net webform

Tags: jquery, asp.net, user-interface, webforms

Not sure what I am missing here, but just moved to 2012 and am having an issue getting an accordian from jquery ui to work in my default.aspx page.

In my default.aspx page, I have this:

```
        <div id="accordian">
            <div>
              <div>
              <h3>Ask 1:</h3>
                <p>
                    Test data 1
                </p>
              </div>
              <div>
              <h3>Ask 2</h3>
                <p>
                    Test data 2
                </p>
              </div>
              <div>
              <h3>Ask 3</h3>
                <p>
                    Test data 3
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Am using the site.master for styling and all. In the head section of the site.master, I have this:

```
<link href="Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#accordian").accordion({ autoHeight: false, collapsible: true });
    });
</script>
```

So when I run this, it should function and display correctly and it is doing neither. Seems the way scripts are loaded in asp.net 4.5 is different now. Is that not true?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything visibly wrong, but I have had no problem moving to VS 2012.

Try running it in IE, it will throw errors better for javascript.  Also, use Firebug in Firefox and see if your CSS and jQuery Scripts get loaded.

You might want to put an alert('some message'); in your script inside your $(document).ready function to see if it even loads and runs.

Comment: I just noticed, you don't have a final <div>... could that be the problem?

Comment: Disable in IE Internet Options under Advanced, Disable Script Debugging.  If you have a script error, it will show you.

Comment: Alright, my stuff was right, but still not working in application yet. Simplified it and put in JSFiddle and it works. So I think my reference to JQuery and Jquery UI isn't correct or something. You can see in sample before I put into Fiddle that I had referenced the css and javascript. Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/prYFt/1/

Comment: What am I missing? I reference the style and scripts in the site.master which is where it should be for a webform project.

Comment: 1) Have you verified that the scripts are getting loaded?
2) Have you verified that the script is running inside your document.ready statement?

Comment: Can you post your default.aspx and your master page

Comment: Not sure how to post the whole file as it seems to limit it here for some reason.

Comment: The default.asp only references site.master and should pull any scripts, css, etc.. from there.

Comment: This is from the head section of the site.master:     <link href="Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert('JS is working');
            $('#accordian').accordion();
        });
    </script>

Comment: Since I do get that alert "JS is working", it tells me that JS is loading. Per the code in my original post (excluding the alert function), it seems maybe there is something being lost on the reference to scripts and whatnot? I even took what is in that JSFiddle as linked above and it doesn't work on the app when running, but it does in JSFiddle.